# ask for location permission in swift

Tags: swiftui

i need the users location in my swiftui app.

if i agree to location sharing everything works, but if i reject and try to  get that permission to work it wont work.

this is the class that handles location logic::

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var locationPermissionStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus?

    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupLocationManager()
    }

    private func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        checkLocationPermission()
    }

    func checkLocationPermission() {
        locationPermissionStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    }

    func requestLocationPermission() {
        // Check if the app already has permission
        if locationPermissionStatus == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else {
            // If permission is already granted or denied, request it again
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        locationPermissionStatus = status
    }
}
```

I need to add the If permission is already granted or denied, request permission again

Comment: If the request is denied, you can't ask for permission again. The best you can do is prompt the user to go to their settings and enable location sharing. Like most (all?) permissions in iOS, you get one shot at prompting for access. If denied, you can show a message if you want but you can only direct the user to go to settings to enable/authorize. You can't reprompt them using the native permissions request.